# Audio Editor in a Django App?

Tags: javascript, python, django, npm, sox

I'm in a little over my head with a project for a client, they want to build an audio editor that will allow the user to trim their uploaded audio files and save them. I've built the file uploader, and the detail view for the individual audio files, my question is how would this best be implemented? I've been looking at 
[Peaks.js](https://github.com/bbc/peaks.js)

and I want to make sure thats the right way to go before diving in. Never used npm in a django project before, is it like using any other js library?

I've also been told about sox, which is great for manipulating the sound files, but what about displaying the sound to the user/editing in the browser? 
Any help or general direction-pointing would be greatly appreciated and could save me a bunch of time potentially.

Comment: I've been to looking to do something similar. Did you figure out a way to do it?

Comment: I did! So I used wavesurfer.js to load the audio file, used the regions plugin (wavesurfer plugin) to select a region, loaded that region to a new audio buffer, then used a recorder worker (RecorderJs) to record the audiobuffer to a wav/blob, and then saved the blob to the DB using xhr. I know it sounds like a lot of work, but it does work. I can send you the github repo, although it may be difficult to parse through